# how to parse HTTPResponse object obtained using google low level api for url fetch- google app engine/java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am using the [low level API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/package-summary.html) to get an HTTPResponse object as the response to my get request to a URL(an API function).

What is the quick and easy way to parse the content of that object? The response will be a JSON response, and I want to use Google GSON to convert that JSON data into Java object...
How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your response is a string, you can do:

```
if (response.getCode() == 200){
   String result = new String(response.getContent(), "UTF-8");


   if (result != null){
       Gson gson = new Gson();
       YourObject obj = gson.fromJson(result,YourObject.class);
   }
}
```

Comment: @Chris- The response will be a JSON object, I am using Google GSON to convert the JSON response to a java object, how do I extract the object? I have also suitably edited the question to show this query (about the JSON part)- I should have put this in the question earlier :(

Comment: I updated my response to show you passing the string to GSON to deserialize it to a pojo.

Comment: In version 4.5 of httpclient you should translate response to string using: 

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8")